# How do I call SOAP methods via PHP?

Tags: php, soap

This is the result of the my var_dump functions:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); echo "</pre>";
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "Read_Result Read(Read $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(55) "ReadByRecId_Result ReadByRecId(ReadByRecId $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(58) "ReadMultiple_Result ReadMultiple(ReadMultiple $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(49) "IsUpdated_Result IsUpdated(IsUpdated $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(67) "GetRecIdFromKey_Result GetRecIdFromKey(GetRecIdFromKey $parameters)"
  [5]=>
  string(40) "Create_Result Create(Create $parameters)"
  [6]=>
  string(64) "CreateMultiple_Result CreateMultiple(CreateMultiple $parameters)"
  [7]=>
  string(40) "Update_Result Update(Update $parameters)"
  [8]=>
  string(64) "UpdateMultiple_Result UpdateMultiple(UpdateMultiple $parameters)"
  [9]=>
  string(40) "Delete_Result Delete(Delete $parameters)"
}
```

I tried to call the read methods, like this:

```
$client->__soapCall("Read" ,  array('No'=>'142JC242'));
```

Actually I don't understand what is **"Read_Result"** ? and **Read(Read $parameters)** ?. and how do I used them  ? thx

Now I'm getting this : **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in..**.

Comment: `Read` is a method name, and `Read_Result` is a returned type.

Comment: @mudasobwa can you be more specific or post an answer ? I would really appreciate it. Thx a lot !

Comment: @Ohgodwhy http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php : “The array of SOAP function prototypes, detailing the return type, the function name and type-hinted paramaters.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have methods:

- Read
- ReadByRecId
- ReadMultiple
- IsUpdated
- GetRecIdFromKey
- Create
- CreateMultiple
- Update
- UpdateMultiple
- Delete

Each method accepts `$parameters` and returns `METHODNAME_Result` value. That’s it. To call method you might try smth like:

```
$client->__soapCall("ReadMultiple", array());
```

At this point we have no clue what parameters are expected by the methods. Where do you get this endpoint from? Was there kinda documentation?

Comment: I have no documentation :( I have to figure it out all by myself. Maybe you can tell me what I have to put as a parameter to my function from here: http://attin.netlogiq.eu/h_b/WebItem.wsdl . This is all new for me.

Comment: If you’ll try to call any function, you’ll get `Uncaught exception: SoapFault: Unauthorized` as a response. That means, this service requires authorization to access the data. Setting SoapHeaders [is described here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php).

Comment: can you post an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126651/getting-unauthorized-when-i-called-a-function-in-soap-via-php ?

Comment: can you post an answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813800/error-while-calling-wsdl-function-server-was-unable-to-process-request-ob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the WSDL file, I would recommend spending some time familiarising yourself with XML Schemas.  You can see from the `<definitions>` tag that this is a WSDL 1 file:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" ... >
```

The WSDL 1.2 specification can be obtained here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-wsdl12-20030303/

When you instantiate a `SoapClient`, you can either use it in WSDL or non-WSDL mode.  In this case, since you have a WSDL file, you can use it in WSDL mode.

The WSDL file provides a specification of the methods that the service provides.  You can directly call the function names as methods of the SoapClient, so for example:

```
$client->Read($params);
```

will call the Read operation.

If you look at this section of the WSDL:

```
    <operation name="Read">
        <input name="Read" message="tns:Read"/>
        <output name="Read_Result" message="tns:Read_Result"/>
    </operation>
```

You'll see that that the Read operation expects an incoming parameter defined by `Read` and will return a response defined by `Read_Result`.

My response is not intended to be comprehensive, but I hope you have enough information to get going.

Comment: can you post an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126651/getting-unauthorized-when-i-called-a-function-in-soap-via-php ? thx