# Getting Unauthorized when I called a function in SOAP via php

Tags: php, soap

After when I am connected successfully, I'm getting all of the function using **__getFunctions();** when I call a function im getting this : **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in /home/netlogiq/public_html/CUSTOM/attin/h_b/db.php:12 Stack trace**.

This is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("WebItem.wsdl", array('proxy_host'     => "83.166.204.26",
                                            'proxy_port'     => 7147,
                                            'proxy_login'    => "xxxxx",
                                            'proxy_password' => "xxxxx",
                                            'trace' => true,
                                            'exception' => true ));

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); echo "</pre>";
echo "<br>";
$client->__soapCall("Read" ,  array('No'=>'142JC242'));
```

Actually I want to know what should I do to get rid of this bug ?  and how i getting all the items from the image bellow ?. The image represent the SOAP UI interface, version 5.0. thx
[image]

Comment: I think, but im not sure that i need ntlm connection. Because in the soap ui i used ntlm. But i don't know how to use it in PHP

Comment: Anyone has some ideea ?